# Custom Java JTree implementation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree, jcomponent

[image]

There are 2 `JTree`: `JTree1` and `JTree2`. Note that the nodes (country, city, colors, blue ...) all will be implemented as `JCheckbox`es so that user can select particular colors for each city or for the whole country by selecting their corresponding checkboxes.

### Problem:

**Q1.** I want that each country or city can have its own colors selected. Means if a user wants `city1.1` to have colors blue and violet and `city2.1` to have colors red, then he first have to select the `city1.1` checkbox and then select blue and violet, and after that when he selects `city2.1`, then the checkboxes blue and violet are deselected automatically so that user can select the colors for `city2.1`. But when the user selects the `city1.1` again, then the `JTree2`should show the selected colors (bule and violet) for city1.1.

> - So for this purpose, Is the JTree (with its nodes as checkboxes) correct option to implement or I should use some other `JComponent`?
> - If JTree is a correct option, then how can I remember the colors of each city?

Answer (score 2):

> So for this purpose, Is the JTree
>   (with its nodes as checkboxes) correct
>   option to implement or I should use
>   some other JComponent?

Not exactly sure what you meant, but I, personally, would not use a [JTree](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) to present the options on the right hand side. I think it is much simpler to present a [JPanel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) that contains the options in this particular case. Left side seems fine for your example, although I don't really know what sort of data is going into the tree.

> If JTree is a correct option, then how
>   can I remember the colors of each
>   city?

Note, I'm going to make a couple of assumptions:

1. The left side that contains your countries and cities remains a [JTree](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) and the right hand side can still be a [JTree](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) or a [JPanel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).
2. You want the options to appear exactly as the user last set it before they select a different node on the left hand side.

The simplest way of achieving this is to add a [TreeSelectionListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeSelectionModel.html#addTreeSelectionListener(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener)) to the tree's (the one containing the countries and cities) selection model. The [TreeSelectionListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeSelectionModel.html#addTreeSelectionListener(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener)) is provided with a [TreeSelectionEvent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionEvent.html) which provides the node that **was** selected and the node that will **become** selected. This will provide you with the opportunity to extract the colour settings that were set for the node that the selection is changing **from** to the one that the selection is changing **to**. The [TreeSelectionListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeSelectionModel.html#addTreeSelectionListener(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener)) should be added to the [TreeSelectionModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeSelectionModel.html) that is obtained from the [JTree](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html), by calling its [getSelectionModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getSelectionModel()) method.

If you use this technique, when you to perform the operation with the last selected options, you'll need to get the options one more time before you perform the operation. For example, if you had a "Save" button, you should check extract the colour settings for which node is selected on the left. This is to capture any changes that the user may have made that the listener has not captured (since the listener is triggered only when the left hand selection changes).

If you need an example, I've written one at http://www.box.net/shared/hgbet4uf6k.